# Column and table headers in same data source as data itself (json data source)

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a json data source for a table element in my report. my json is-

```
[{
        "line_num": {
            "oldVal": "1",
            "newVal": "5"
        },
        "product1": {
            "oldVal": "product1old",
            "newVal": "product1new"
        }
}, {
    "line_num": {
        "oldVal": "4",
        "newVal": "7"
    },
    "product2": {
        "oldVal": "product2old",
        "newVal": "product2new"
    }
}
]
```

and that worked for my report, but then  I needed to add the columns and table headers from the data source.

so I tried to add it as an own object in that json array above like this:

```
[{
        "tableH": "My Table Header"  ,         
        "col1H": "Line No."  ,     
        "col2H": "My Product"  
    }, {
        "line_num": {
            "oldVal": "1",
            "newVal": "5"
        },
        "product1": {
            "oldVal": "product1old",
            "newVal": "product1new"
        }

    }, {
        "line_num": {
            "oldVal": "4",
            "newVal": "7"
        },
        "product2": {
            "oldVal": "product2old",
            "newVal": "product2new"
        }
    }
]
```

but the problem is that when there is a lot of lines larger then the page's height, the headers on the second page were null which make sense because the first obj (the headers obj) is unknown from the second line on,

but I have no idea how to pass my headers from server in another way.

the only way that worked is to add all of the headers to each obj in the array, but I can not do it because its defiantly wrong.

I also tried to put the lines as an array like this:

```
[{
        "tableH": "My Table Header"  ,        
        "col1H": "Line No."  ,        
        "col2H": "My Product"  ,
        "Lines": [{
                "line_num": {
                    "oldVal": "1",
                    "newVal": "5"
                },
                "product1": {
                    "oldVal": "product1old",
                    "newVal": "product1new"
                }

            }, {
                "line_num": {
                    "oldVal": "4",
                    "newVal": "7"
                },
                "product2": {
                    "oldVal": "product2old",
                    "newVal": "product2new"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

but then the fields did not pass correctly, it passed for example for - lines.line_num.newVal , the field is : ["5","7"].

I really need help with that and I'll appreciate any helpful reply.

Comment: We could use some sample .jrxml file to get an idea about your desired output. Do you really need to use a table? What version of JasperReports are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bad idea to mix your dataset with static data. My first attempt would be to fetch static data through a scriptlet.

Otherwise, you can add the column names in a group header component and leverage the functionality provided by the `isReprintHeaderOnEachPage` attribute of the group.

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html#group_isReprintHeaderOnEachPage